# Switch carrier error

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, lenovo, lenovo-a6000-plus

I have Lenovo A6000 plus. Still running on 4.4.4
I tried update my OS via Lenovo update as I haven't done it a long time and Lollipop is there
Download seems fine, and it changed into recovery mode to update.
Then I get a error saying"your phone has not switched carrier and cannot upgrade" and the installation gets aborted.
Some site says I need to install some ota file.Is there any easy way to solve this?

Comment: [very similar if not same problem and solution here](http://enterpriseadmins.blogspot.in/2015/10/lenovo-a6000.html?_escaped_fragment_#!)

Comment: @beeshyams That page cannot fix this problem.